# How to use Python to read the whole binary file created by Fortran

Tags: python, scipy, fortran

I use Fortran to create a binary file which contains multiple lines:

```
Program write_binary
implicit none
integer i
real x
open(10,file="test.dat",form="unformatted")
do i=1,10
   write(10),i*1.0,i*2.0
end do
close(10)
end
```

Then I use Python, trying to read the whole file. However, the FortranFile package can only read line by line (see code below). Is there any way that I can read all lines of the binary files created by Fortran? Great thanks.

```
from scipy.io import FortranFile
import numpy as np
f=FortranFile('test.dat','r')
x=read_reals(dtype='f4')
print(x)
```

Comment: There are no lines in Fortran unformatted files; there are records. And yes, `FortranFile` can only read one at a time. Use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often write data in Fortran and read it in Python. I will explain it here for a multiple 3D arrays case since it is more general and easily adaptable to a 1D array.

From Fortran, I write the data with the following loop:

```
file = 'my_fortran_data.dat'
open(99, file=file, status = 'replace', action = 'write', form = 'unformatted', access='stream')
    do k = 1,L
        do j = 1,M
            do i = 1,N
                write(99) u(i,j,k), v(i,j,k), w(i,j,k)
            end do
        end do
    end do
close(99)
```

Note that I write my data in `stream` access. Hence I do not record the begining and end of each record (making the file size smaller).

From Python, I use the following function to read the data in:

```
def read_data(file, dtype, stream):
    """
    Return the components of a 3D vector field stored in binary format.
    The data field is supposed to have been written as: (for k; for j; for i;) where the last dimension
    is the quickest varying index. Each record should have been written as: u, v, w.
    The returned components are always converted in np.double precision type.

    Args:
        dim: number of dimensions
        dtype: numpy dtype object. Single or double precision expected.
        stream: type of access of the binary output. If true, the file can only contain data. 
    If false, there is a 4-byte header and footer around each "record"
            in the binary file (can happen in some Fortran compilers if access != 'stream').
    """
    if stream:
        shape = (L, M, N, 3)
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        data = np.fromfile(file=f, dtype=dtype).reshape(shape)
        f.close()
        u = data[:, :, :, 0].transpose(2, 1, 0)
        v = data[:, :, :, 1].transpose(2, 1, 0)
        w = data[:, :, :, 2].transpose(2, 1, 0)
        del data

    else:
        shape = (L, M, N, 5)
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        data = np.fromfile(file=f, dtype=dtype).reshape(shape)
        f.close()
        u = data[:, :, :, 1].transpose(2, 1, 0)
        v = data[:, :, :, 2].transpose(2, 1, 0)
        w = data[:, :, :, 3].transpose(2, 1, 0)
        del data

    u = u.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
    v = v.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
    w = w.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
    return(u, v, w)
```

Note that I always convert the data into double precision but you can omit this last step if not required.

For your case use `shape=(10,2)` for the `stream` access or `shape=(10,4)` otherwise.